# Windows Update setting won't save

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

first time post. Ever since I refreshed my windows 8 laptop, Windows Update setting won't save.

**Background:**
On my laptop I had upgraded from Windows 8 to 8.1. Eventually I set Windows Update to "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them" because my pc was running slower and the downloads were bogging it down.

A few weeks ago I "refreshed" my computer which took it back to windows 8. I upgraded to 8.1 and installed all updates. I then changed the Windows Update setting to "Install updates automatically."

**Problem:**
The Windows Update setting won't save. I change it, and save it. But it seems that any time my computer checks for updates, that setting reverts to "Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them".

I contacted Microsoft support and had an online chat. The support person remotely accessed my pc, changed the setting back to "Automatically check..." and then restarted. She then told me it was fixed. But this is what I'd been doing all along.

Within minutes of finishing that online session, I "reserved" my copy of Windows 10. I then checked the Windows Update setting and it had reverted to "Check for updates..."

Let me know if there's any other information that would help solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Simplest solution, if you plan to upgrade to Windows 10, just wait for July 29th.  This is a personal computer that isn't on a domain and you are making these changes as an Administrator user?

Comment: Yes, making changes as an Administrator. Hopefully the upgrade will fix the issue, but it's certainly isn't urgent so I could wait. Seems like there might be a registry setting that's not being set properly or something.